# Primefaces Dialog acquiring place, if it is hidden. How to remove place acquired by it?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<pou:dialog id="cart-dialog"
            header="Checkout"
            widgetVar="cartModalDialog"
            modal="true"
            height="500"
            width="900"
            position="400, 100">
</pou:dialog>
```

I have 5 dialogs on a single page but they all are hidden because they will be shown on click event of a button. But before triggered they have acquired a place on the page and vertical scroll appear.

How to release acquired place from them?

Comment: It's probably something else. When dialogs are hidden they get a `display: none` style, which means they have no effect on layout at all: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display

Comment: but they acquire place. i want to get release that place.

Comment: How do you know it's the dialogs? What do browser dev tools say about those dialogs? Post a minimal page that reproduces the problem, specify affected browsers, and where the scrollbar appears exactly.

Comment: dear golovano, i am using primeface dialog component, so i am aware of it what i am using. scroll shown vertically on page. i have include 5 dialogs in the page.

Comment: Not enough information provided to answer the question. Problem is not reproducible on PrimeFaces 5.1.